# Собственный BlendMode\Xfermode для Paint в Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Рисую на `Canvas` круги стилусом, используя `Paint` с различным цветом и альфой. И мне нужен такой режим смешивания, который будет заменять `alpha` пикселей на `Canvas` только тогда, когда `alpha` пикселя нового круга больше чем `alpha` пикселя на `Canvas`.

Примерно так:

```
a = max(a, aNew);
c = cNew;
```

Пробовал различные `Xfermode`, `PorterDuff` и `BlendMode`, но всё не то, что нужно. (или что то упустил?)

Можно ли задать свой алгоритм для смешивания?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как то запутанно вы объяснили, нет понятия "нового" пикселя (src dist). Заменять вам только альфа канал или весь цвет? Лучше привести пример картинку.

Comment: @Style-7 , добавил пример-картинку